# Clickonce shows Install button instead of Upgrade for already installed application

Tags: clickonce

When we publish an update to our application, some users randomly see the Application Install window instead of the Upgrade window.

We've checked that the application is already installed (it's listed in Program and Features) yet ClickOnce wants the user to install it again.

All other users see the Upgrade window as normal.  It's not user specific as it happens to random users at random times.

Normally this wouldn't be an issue but some users do not want to be forced to update unless it's a forced update (roaming users who out of the office for example).  The trouble is these users are forced to run the install because they can't skip the update.

The deployment is signed with a valid certificate.  Deployment is via a URL.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar issue.. where we had an old clickonce app that was built/published 2 or 3 years ago. Now, we have a new version that was published with TFS build, and I am having to re install instead of simply getting an update message.

Comment: Our issue was due to users pinning the application to the Task Bar.  Windows then used the Task Bar location on the hard drive to install the application upgrades instead of the users location.  Sometimes windows would clear the task bar folder which would cause the install to be broken requiring the application to be re-installed.

The only solution we have found so far is to ask users not to pin the application to the task bar.

Your issue may be different though.  Compare the appname.application file (open with notepad) in your install folder and see the differences.